# How do I remove the comma if there is no value?

Tags: php, html, templates

I have a select field that gets its values from a database table. Not all records in the database have all fields. Some are null. I want my select field to show the name,iata,icao - a combination of these three seperated by a comma. The issue is that some of my fields do not have an icao and some do not have an iaata. Is there a way for me to alter my code such that if there is no icao or iata the comma is ignored.

Please see below:

[image]

[image]

The code i need to alter is below:

```
 <select name="airport1" class="airport1" id="airport1">
                    <option selected value="Add">Select Airport</option>

                    <?php
                    $mysqli = NEW MYSQLI("localhost", "root", "", "airports");
                    $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT name,iata,icao 
    FROM airports order by name ASC;
    ");

?>

                    <?php
                    while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()){
                        $name = $rows['name'];
                        $iata = $rows['iata'];
                        $icao = $rows['icao'];
                        echo "<option value='$name,$iata,$icao'>$name,$iata,$icao</option>";
                    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether `iata` or `icao` is *null* before appending them to the string:

```
...
while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
    $name = $rows['name'];
    $iata = $rows['iata'];
    $icao = $rows['icao'];

    $displayValue = $name;
    
    if ($iata) {
        $displayValue .= ", " . $iata;
    }
    
    if ($icao) {
        $displayValue .= ", " . $icao;
    }

    echo "<option value='$name,$iata,$icao'>$displayValue</option>";
}
...
```

**OR:** You can use [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to join the non-null values with a comma

```
...
while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
    $name = $rows['name'];
    $iata = $rows['iata'];
    $icao = $rows['icao'];

    //create an array of non-null values
    $nonNullValues = array_filter([$name, $iata, $icao]);

    //use implode to join the non-null values with a comma
    $displayValue = implode(', ', $nonNullValues);

    echo "<option value='$name,$iata,$icao'>$displayValue</option>";
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is put those values in a list

```
$options = [$name,$iata,$icao];
```

then you can remove the "empty" values

```
$options = array_filter($options);
```

and use them to populate what you need to populate, example:

```
echo "<option value='". implode(',', $options) ."'>...";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use trim to remove trailing commas and a regex to replace if multiple comma consecutive (in this case, only field iata is null):

```
while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()){
    $name = $rows['name'];
    $iata = $rows['iata'];
    $icao = $rows['icao'];
    $option = "$name,$iata,$icao";
    $option = trim($option,",");
    $option = preg_replace("/,{2,}/",",",$option );
    echo "<option value='$option '>$option </option>";
}
```